# Bokeh Server integration with Flask error

Tags: python, google-maps, flask, bokeh

I'm stuck at a point where I try to integrate my bokeh server app with Flask. I am using the GMapOptions library in bokeh to generate a visualization showing the distribution of my client data across a geographical area. I get the following error when I run the Flask app code,

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'google_api_key' and 'map_options'
```

I get the same message in the command prompt when I run the bokeh server app independently in the command prompt using the bokeh serve command, but the app runs nevertheless. Apparently, it is some sort of a bug in the bokeh library that generates the message but according to the developers of the library this should not prevent my app from running, which it does'nt when run independently. I reported the bug to the developers of the library, https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7985.

Here is my code for the visualization,

```
from bokeh.plotting import output_file
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import Button, GMapOptions, ColumnDataSource, CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.models import *
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pymssql



# parameters
server = 'X.X.X.X\PQR'
db = 'ABC'

# Create the connection
conn = pymssql.connect(database = db, host = server)
cur = conn.cursor()
map_options = GMapOptions(lat=37.686293, lng=-97.3614409, map_type="roadmap", zoom=13)
p = gmap("My Google Maps API Key", map_options, title="Resolutions Clients", plot_width=1000, plot_height=600)

sql = """
        with CTE AS
            (SELECT
            CR.ClientID, CR.Latitude, CR.Longtitude
            FROM 
            Company C LEFT JOIN ClientRegistration CR on C.CompanyID = CR.CompanyID
            WHERE
            C.CompanyID = 555 AND (CR.Latitude IS NOT NULL AND CR.Longtitude IS NOT NULL)
            )
        SELECT
        C.ClientID, C.Latitude, C.Longtitude, CL.Sex
        FROM
        CTE C LEFT JOIN Clients CL on C.ClientID = CL.ClientID
    """

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)



df[['Latitude', 'Longtitude']] = df[['Latitude', 'Longtitude']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].astype('str')

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=37.686293, lng=-97.3614409, map_type="roadmap", zoom=10)
p = gmap("My Google Maps API Key", map_options, title="Resolutions Clients Genderwise", plot_width=1000,
             plot_height=600)

lat = df['Latitude'].tolist()
lon = df['Longtitude'].tolist()
sex = df['Sex'].tolist()

source = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(latitude=lat,
                  longitude=lon,
                  gender=sex
                  )
)


color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(factors=['M', 'F', 'U'], palette=['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'])


p.circle(x="longitude", y="latitude", size=4, fill_alpha=0.9, source=source,
             fill_color={'field': 'gender', 'transform': color_mapper},
             line_color={'field': 'gender', 'transform': color_mapper})

x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

p.circle(x, y, legend="Male", color="red")
p.circle(x, 2 * y, legend="Female", color="Blue")
p.circle(x, 3 * y, legend="Unknown", color="Green")

def update():
    # query db
    curdoc().clear()
    sql = """
            with CTE AS
                (SELECT
                CR.ClientID, CR.Latitude, CR.Longtitude
                FROM
                Company C LEFT JOIN ClientRegistration CR on C.CompanyID = CR.CompanyID
                WHERE
                C.CompanyID = 555 AND (CR.Latitude IS NOT NULL AND CR.Longtitude IS NOT NULL)
                )
            SELECT
                C.ClientID, C.Latitude, C.Longtitude,
                CASE WHEN age > 0 AND age <= 15 THEN 'Children'
                     WHEN age > 15 AND age <= 30 THEN 'Young Adult'
                     WHEN age > 30 AND age <= 55 THEN 'Adult'
                     WHEN age > 55 THEN 'Senior Citizen'
                     END AS 'Age_Group'
            FROM
            CTE C LEFT JOIN Clients CL on C.ClientID = CL.ClientID
    """
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

    df[['Latitude', 'Longtitude']] = df[['Latitude', 'Longtitude']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    df['Age_Group'] = df['Age_Group'].astype('str')

    df['Latitude'].median()
    df['Longtitude'].median()

    map_options = GMapOptions(lat=37.686293, lng=-97.3614409, map_type="roadmap", zoom=10)

    p = gmap("My Google Maps API Key", map_options, title="Resolutions Clients Age wise",
             plot_width=1000, plot_height=600)

    lat = df['Latitude'].tolist()
    lon = df['Longtitude'].tolist()
    age = df['Age_Group'].tolist()

    source = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(latitude=lat,
                  longitude=lon,
                  age_Group=age
                  )
    )

    color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(factors=['Children', 'Young Adult', 'Adult', 'Senior Citizen'],
                                          palette=['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow'])

    p.add_tools(LassoSelectTool())
    p.add_tools(ZoomInTool())
    p.add_tools(ZoomOutTool())

    p.circle(x="longitude", y="latitude", size=4, fill_alpha=0.9, source=source,
             fill_color={'field': 'age_Group', 'transform': color_mapper},
             line_color={'field': 'age_Group', 'transform': color_mapper})

    x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)

    p.circle(x, y, legend="Children : Age <= 15", color="red")
    p.circle(x, 2 * y, legend="Young Adult : 30 >= Age > 15", color="Blue")
    p.circle(x, 3 * y, legend="Adult : 55 >= Age > 30 ", color="Green")
    p.circle(x, 4 * y, legend="Senior Citizen : Age > 55", color="Yellow")

    curdoc().add_root(row(button1, button2))
    curdoc().add_root(column(p))

def update1():
    # query db
    curdoc().clear()
    sql = """
            with CTE AS
                (SELECT
                CR.ClientID, CR.Latitude, CR.Longtitude
                FROM
                Company C LEFT JOIN ClientRegistration CR on C.CompanyID = CR.CompanyID
                WHERE
                C.CompanyID = 555 AND (CR.Latitude IS NOT NULL AND CR.Longtitude IS NOT NULL)
                )
            SELECT
            C.ClientID, C.Latitude, C.Longtitude, CL.Sex
            FROM
            CTE C LEFT JOIN Clients CL on C.ClientID = CL.ClientID
        """
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

    df[['Latitude', 'Longtitude']] = df[['Latitude', 'Longtitude']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].astype('str')

    map_options = GMapOptions(lat=37.686293, lng=-97.3614409, map_type="roadmap", zoom=10)
    p = gmap("My Google Maps API Key", map_options, title="Resolutions Clients Genderwise",
             plot_width=1000,
             plot_height=600)

    lat = df['Latitude'].tolist()
    lon = df['Longtitude'].tolist()
    sex = df['Sex'].tolist()

    source = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(latitude=lat,
                  longitude=lon,
                  gender=sex
                  )
    )


    color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(factors=['M', 'F', 'U'], palette=['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'])

    p.circle(x="longitude", y="latitude", size=4, fill_alpha=0.9, source=source,
             fill_color={'field': 'gender', 'transform': color_mapper},
             line_color={'field': 'gender', 'transform': color_mapper})

    x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)

    p.circle(x, y, legend="Male", color="red")
    p.circle(x, 2 * y, legend="Female", color="Blue")
    p.circle(x, 3 * y, legend="Unknown", color="Green")

    curdoc().add_root(row(button1, button2))
    curdoc().add_root(column(p))

# add a button widget and configure with the call back
button1 = Button(label="Gender")
button2 = Button(label="Age")

button1.on_click(update1)
button2.on_click(update)

# put the button and plot in a layout and add to the document
curdoc().add_root(row(button1, button2))
curdoc().add_root(column(p))
```

Here is my app.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bokeh.embed import autoload_static
from bokeh.client import pull_session

#instantiating the flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

#create the index page function

@app.route("/")
def index():
    session = pull_session(url="http://localhost:5006/Button_test_update_version2")
    bokeh_script = autoload_static(None, url="http://localhost:5006/Button_test_update_version2", session_id=session.id)
    return render_template("index.html", bokeh_script=bokeh_script)

#run the app
if __name__ == "_main_":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my index.html file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Therasoft Visualization</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={‌{url_for('static', filename='css/main.css')}}>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Therasoft Visualization</h1>
<div>
    {‌{bokeh_script|safe}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my main.css file,

```
h3{
    color : olive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Resolved in https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/7998

---

The answer was in the code from your other issue, you have to pass the values as keyword args:

```
 p = gmap(google_api_key="My Google Maps API Key", map_options=map_options, ...)
```

I'm not sure why that is offhand, seems like a bug that passing the args positionally does not work, but that workaround should suffice.

Comment: bigreddot, thanks for your response but even after passing the values as  keyword arguments, the issue still persists.